# How to serialize / parse protobuf object between Ruby and Java?

Tags: java, ruby, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

What is the correct way to serialize a protobuf object in ruby and parse in Java? This is for automated testing, we are listening for this message on a Rabbit queue.

Publisher (Ruby):

```
protoNew = Protobuf::Request.new
protoNew.request = request
protoNew.id = id.to_i
protoNew.authentication = authentication

return protoNew.serialize_to_string
```

Consumer (Java):

```
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) 
    {
        ProtoRequest protoRequest;
        try {
            protoRequest = ProtoRequest.parseFrom(message.getBody());
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e1) {
            logger.error("Error parsing protobuf", e1);
        }
```

Here is the error I am seeing:

> Error parsing protobuf: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
>           at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:94) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.checkLastTagWas(CodedInputStream.java:174) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:139) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]
>           at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49) [protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how you are packaging the `protoNew.serialize_to_string` output such that it becomes content of JMS message for Java Code.  I guess something is getting messed due to char encoding.

As a work around, you can do Base 64 encoding of the binary output of `protoNew.serialize_to_string`, and do Base 64 decoding at Java end.

```
require "base64"
...
return Base64.encode64 protoNew.serialize_to_string
```

On Java Side,

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
...
protoRequest = ProtoRequest.parseFrom(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getBody()))
```

One thing bad about the above solution is that it will result in bigger payload size compared to pure binary form.

PS: Please note that if I write output of `person.serialize_to_string` to a file in Ruby side, and read that file on Java, it seems to work fine

```
f = File.open("data.dat", "wb")
f << person.serialize_to_string
f.close
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked with a small change, I ended up using "protoRequest = ProtoRequest.parseFrom( Base64.decode( new String( message.getBody() ) ) );" on the java side, since message.getBody() was returning a byte array.

Comment: Similar success here but afaict `serialize_to_string` may no longer be a method.  I did `Base64.strict_encode64 Prefab::Request.encode(user)`

The strict leaves out the newlines which have only lead to pain for me in the past.